# How to use MVC4 SimpleMembership WebSecurity features in one VS project, but affect a different project in the same solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I have a VS C# solution using two different MVC4 with SimpleMembership EF projects. Each project has it's own database schema etc. separate from the other.  I have it setup so that project B can access project A's models, and do CRUD operations.  However, when I try to create a new user (for example using Websecurity.CreateUserAndAccount)all of that work will occur on that project only, and only affecting the database of that given project.  So the question is, how can I use Websecurity features in project B, but actually affect the database in project A? (ie, somehow tell my project B that for this Websecurity.Whatever call, actually update/insert etc. into project A's database instead).  Trying to avoid having to create my own custom membership if possible.
     Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Do you want updates to WebSecurity to affect databases A and B, or just database A?

Comment: Just have the configuration string for SimpleMembership in project B point to project A's database.